# Cookie crashes a Wordpress website

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I've been working on a plugin for WordPress for a while now, and everything is working fine so far. I've tested my plugin on a personal website many times, with success.

Although, now, I've moved my plugin to a different, existing website. When my plugin creates a cookie, the complete website crashes and gives me the error: "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".

When I inspect my cookie browser, I can see that the cookie has been successfully made. However, every page on the website is not accessible anymore until I clear that cookie...

The cookie is called **cart**, is made on path **/** and contains the following content:
**[{"product_id":"19","firstName":"Test","lastName":"Test","city":"Amsterdam","brand":"KTM","number":0,"licence":"","transponder":0,"match":""}]**

I'm adding the cookie by creating an empty JavaScript object, adding values to it and pushing the cookie with document.cookie:

```
var item = {};
item.product_id = product_id;
item.firstName = firstName;
item.lastName = lastName;
item.city = city;
item.brand = brand;
item.number = number;
item.licence = hasLicence == 1 ? licence : "";
item.transponder = hasTransponder == 1 ? transponder : 0;
item.match = isMatch;
cart.push(item);

document.cookie = "webshop_cart=" + JSON.stringify(cart) + ";path=/";
```

What can this possibly be? I'm really out of ideas for this one, it's stressing me out!

Comment: As it is now, it's impossible to answer your question, as no cookie should prevent your website from loading. What code, as a [mcve], do you use to check for that cookie?

Comment: Okay. I'll try and post some minimal code.

Comment: I've added the code I'm using to create a cookie. I don't see how the cookie is not crashing the website, since not a single page is loading! Even pages that don't use my plugin...

Comment: What about your PHP code you use to check for your cookie?

Comment: Even when I comment out every single line of code that uses the cookie, it still crashes the website.

Comment: The website where this problem is occuring redirect to a different domain. Can that be the problem?

For example:
I go to example.com. It redirects me to example.otherdomain.com

Comment: It's possible when you redirect to a different domain, it redirects back (and so on)

Comment: I don't understand... How does my cookie have anything to do with that?

Comment: Also I've tried adding a cookie with the same name but a simple value like "test". That seems to work...
I'm lost for words...

Answer (score 0):

Try URI encoding your cookie:

```
var item = {};
item.product_id = product_id;
item.firstName = firstName;
item.lastName = lastName;
item.city = city;
item.brand = brand;
item.number = number;
item.licence = hasLicence == 1 ? licence : "";
item.transponder = hasTransponder == 1 ? transponder : 0;
item.match = isMatch;
cart.push(item);

document.cookie = "webshop_cart=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(cart)) + ";path=/";
```

Then decode your cookie when you need it again using `decodeURIComponent`.

Comment: Although I really expected this to work, it unfortunately gave me the exact same result. :(

I'm trying to encrypt my cookie, which works ands keeps the website from crashing. Unfortunately, I haven't found an encryption method which I can easily decrypt again in my PHP backend...